# Start a spring batch job when already within a transaction

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-batch

I have simple Spring-Service that (among other tasks) starts a spring batch job with the following code:

```
@Autowired
private JobRegistry jobRegistry;

@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

public void startMyJob() {
    Job job = jobRegistry.getJob("myJobName");
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters();
    jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
}
```

This works fine, as long as there is no transaction active when the Serivce-Method is called. However, with an active transaction, I get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client).
```

I cannot easily remove the existing transaction, since it is implied due to some framework code that is not within my reach.

So, how can I start the job anyway within this context? The new job just should not use the existing transaction. It could just start its own transaction - but how to configure it to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.ValidateTransactionState`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.html#setValidateTransactionState%28boolean%29), but use carefully (Warning: Dragons ahead).

To use another transaction you can inject a custom `SimpleJobLauncher.executor` with method `Executor.run` marked as @Transactional() (or create a custom `JobLauncher` and do the same trick on method `run`).

I haven't tried because I haven't faced the problem, but hope can help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Marking the run-Method with (at)Transactional does not solve the problem on its own, because the Validator still finds the existing transaction. I did a combination of both now: mark the run-Method (at)Transactional and disabled the validator - works fine in my dev-environment, although I dont really feel confident about this solution.

Comment: Hi @Jack, how do you disable the validator?

Comment: Its a property of the JobRepository. When you define the jobRepository Bean, you set the `validateTransactionState` property to false.

Comment: `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` on a custom job launcher's run method did the trick for me.  There was no need to disable the validator, as per hint in answer below.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem. In particular, I was starting my jobs from within a class that was annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`. To work around this, I started my jobs from a somewhere, where I had no active transaction. Then I ran into your problem as described above - and here is how I solved it:

set `validateTransactionState`to false on the JobRepository - it now ignored the transactions that were automatically created in the class my `ItemProcessor` called (because said class was annotated with @Transcational, as explained above).

This made my jobs run just fine. However, I wasn't sure if I was now dealing with 2 open transactions and wanted to be sure I was not. So I also removed the transcational annnotation on the class level and moved it to all public methods, except the ones called by my Itemprocessor. Thus I solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

My solution was that the method starting the job needed to be annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` this would suspend the current transaction and resume after execution.

You can set `transactionAttribute` on your readers and writers if you need anything different from defaults.

I did not need `setValidateTransactionState(false)` on the `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` or `JobRepository`

Answer (score 4):

I've dealt with this by creating a separate bean AsyncJobLauncher which has a run method with the same signature as JobLauncher and delegates to the real one, but marked with Spring's @Async. So, the launching of the job happened in the background on a new thread, so it was in its own transaction.

Comment: Yes but doing like that you cannot catch validation errors that happen on the async thread launched, the errors will not be received by the main thread and eventually returned back to the caller of the main thread